# Take a URI as a parameter

Tags: playframework

Im considering using play for an application I'm designing. But I have an interesting problem.

The site is a sorta kinda CDN.  Think readthedocs.org-ish.  Only mine far more generic than readthedocs.

The problem im trying to overcome is passing a uri as a parameter.  so if i give the url

```
mysite.com/viewer/group2/app1/1.0.0/static/bla/bla/foo.jpg
```

`viewer` is the controller.  `group2`, `app1`, and `1.0.0` are simple path parameters, but the last parameter is `static/bla/bla/foo.jpg`

how do i do that in play routing?

another alternative i suppose would be

```
mysite.com/viewer/group2/app1/1.0.0?static/bla/bla/foo.jpg
```

but I'm afraid that this would interfere with the existing HTML.  This app is being designed as a corporate repository for javadoc, scaladoc, sphinxdoc, doxygen, etc.  Our CI server will handle compiling the docs, zipping them, and submitting them to the rest service.  The rest service will then unzip them and most likely push the individual files into S3.  But i need this viewer controller to map the URL's that are in the existing HTML to the S3 url's and inside of an iframe on the page, view the html and have the html function normally (without me having to parse everything and replace url's)  but at the same time, this site is rather limited if i don't have deep linking capability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic part to capture more than one URI path segment, separated by forward slashes, you can define a dynamic part using the `*id` syntax, which uses the `.+` regular expression:

`GET   /files/*name          controllers.Application.download(name)`

Here for a request like GET `/files/images/logo.png`, the name dynamic part will capture the `images/logo.png` value.